# Where in algebraic topology does category theory become essential?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

I recently finished a first graduate course in algebraic topology, and my institution's final undergrad course in smooth manifolds. Since courses ended, I have been studying de Rham cohomology, in the process returning to many of the topics I learned in my courses and strengthening my understanding as necessary.

Throughout, I have started to become interested in category theory. But so far, the category theory I have seen has been basic: how $\pi_n$ is a functor, how pullback is a (contravariant) functor, how (co)homology is a functor. This amounts to acknowledging certain similarities between the constructions we've been doing, but I've yet to see this ghost in the code become a *primary* concern.

> In algebraic topology, what are the earliest instances in which category theory becomes essential to obtaining results?

I am particularly interested in answers involving topics in algebraic topology that I can conceivably understand by the end of this summer, from the starting point of de Rham cohomology and the very basics of category theory.

---

**As to what I mean by essential:** I have been thinking about what 'essential' should mean here. The problem is that I have not seen much c.t. in action in a.t., so there's some 'I don't know what I don't know' going on here.

I know, in general, that many people affirm that a student should begin learning a subject 'classically,' to some extent, so that there is motivation, and so that subtleties are not lost on the student. In this sense, withholding information is justifiable. **So by 'essential,' perhaps a good interpretation is 'it would be *completely* unjustifiable to withhold category theory from the student learning/proving this.'**

Comment: What would you consider to be "essential"? For instance, the universal coefficients theorem is considered to be a result in algebraic topology but it's just a straightforward application of homological algebra.

Comment: @ZhenLin I was also thinking that this needed clarification. I'm going to sleep on it for now, because I am exhausted. To any potential answer-er who reads this before then: please interpret it as you see fit.

Comment: I don't think that category theory is essential to anything. Everything can be done without it. The category theory is an abstraction, a tool, that allows treating analogus things in the same way. Instead of dealing with each thing separately. But it doesn't mean it is necessary. Similarly how group theory is not essential to anything, you can prove every theorem on concrete groups one by one. Easier? Yes. Essential? No. Anyway, this looks like a philosophical question.

Comment: @freakish Try to develop the theory of model categories without category theory.

Comment: @freakish This is not how the word "essential" works. Nothing is "necessary" for anything except something like ZFC. However if you are to claim that for instance no geometric ideas are essential for algebraic topology (can do without it!) then your terminology is very suspicious. 
Not to mention that the premise that everything can be done at least formally without CT is obviously false (and it's far from obvious what is really dispensable: CT or, say, set theory)

Comment: Did you ever wonder about the precise meaning of the word "natural" when it appears in AT? (And it appears quite early when you learn the subject.) CT is usually hidden in the answer (if you ever get a straight answer).

Comment: The power of the category theory point of view is the manner in which its abstractions clarify and simplify and give you power to prove more things, more quickly, with more applications. Let me suggest that you look at the proof of the "no retract theorem", which says that there is no continuous map $B^n \mapsto S^{n-1}$ which restricts to the identity map on $S^{n-1}=\partial B^n$ (this is the key step in the proof of the Brouwer fixed point theorem). Imagine the proof in two ways: with the word "functor", and without the word "functor". Compare those proofs, and decide which is better.